# Is it necessary to protect destroy method in Laravel from an authenticated user that did not create a post

Tags: laravel, middleware

I have the following middleware in my `PostController`.

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth')->except(['index', 'show']);
    }
```

I understand any authenticated user can still edit a post by visiting `localhost/posts/{post}/edit` so I've protected that by the following code.

```
 public function edit(Post $post)
    {
        if(auth()->user()->id === $post->user_id){
            $categories = Category::all();
            return view('edit-post', compact(['post', 'categories']));
        } else{
            abort(403, 'Unauthorized.');
        }

    }
```

Now, I'm wondering is it necessary to protect the destroy method? Is it possible for an authenticated user to delete a post they didn't create in this case? If they can could I kindly know how they can?

My destroy method

```
   public function destroy(Post $post)
    {
        Storage::disk('public')->delete($post->imagePath);
        $post->delete();
        return redirect(route('posts.index'))->with('flash', 'Post Deleted Successfully');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

one easy way to protect all your methods that need authentification is to use relations.

You are sending a post id in the URL by use model injection to preload `$post` from DB. Avoid that and use the id of the post yourself

```
public function destroy($postId)
    {
        $post = auth()->user()->posts()->findOrFail($postId);
        Storage::disk('public')->delete($post->imagePath);
        $post->delete();
        return redirect(route('posts.index'))->with('flash', 'Post Deleted Successfully');
    }
```

The route will return a 404 if the post id is not one of the user owned posts.

Same for the edit

```
public function edit($postId)
{
    $post = auth()->user()->posts()->findOrFail($postId);
    $categories = Category::all();
    return view('edit-post', compact(['post', 'categories']));
}
```

As for the change in response code 404 instead of a 403, it is on purpose, since the user is authenticated and you dont want any user to know if another post with random ID that is not his exists or not hence 404. like if he put a non existing post id to delete or edit.

Comment: I agree on the 404 instead of 403, thanks. Regarding the suggested method, 2 questions on it: 1. Does route model binding way have a problem why should it be avoided?  Cause I'm okay with either way and if  I protect destroy method  the same way as the edit method it would still work.

2. How can an authenticated user delete a post they did not create without checking if they are the ones who created the post in the destroy method. I'm curious and I'd like to do that practically and see so as to fulfill my curiosity if it's necessary to protect it from authenticated user?

Comment: @AlphyGacheru 1- every features is not a must use in every situation. here you need to delete a post related to the user in session, while model binding just load the post by id strictly.(if it was in an admin controller, model binding would be perfect to use) 2- using the method i presented. it doesnt do an extra query or anything, heck the query is even faster because you're using two indexes (user_id & posts.id)

Comment: I get your point, agreed though I'm not sure you answered my last question or I'm the one who didn't understand. What I meant, If I wanted to edit a post not protected  I would visit `localhost/posts/{post}/edit`. Assuming we've not protected the destroy method, what url would I need to visit to delete a post?

Comment: How to write that in the address bar to delete cause when I try `localhost/posts/23/delete` or  `localhost/posts/slug/delete` since I'm using slug as `RouteKeyName` then it doesn't delete a post?

Comment: Yes I have post method. My curiosity is how will an attacker delete a post if it wasn't protected. From your explanation would it be correct to say you cannot delete using post method via the address bar as suggested by @Moamed in the next answer and what I thought as well would be possible?

Comment: huh? your question is not clear for me but if i got it right, let's say if a route is post method, you cannot access it from the browser's bar (get method) will return 405 Method Not Allowed.

Comment: I  agree with @N69S in the last comment, Short answer is [DON'T TRUST THE CLIENT](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/105389/dont-trust-the-client).

Answer (score 0):

First, you should be read about [Laravel policy](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#writing-policies), which will make your code more clear.

For destroy method,

I will give you an example, you can try it BTW

**post_table**

| id | user_id | title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 40 | Post1 |
| 2 | 50 | Post2 |

If the user `id: 40` tries to delete the post witch id is `id: 1` there is no problem,
BUT let's say the user knows about the web app and just changes the `id` in the URL `localhost/posts/2/delete`, He/She will delete any post without policy.

Comment: Tried but it did not delete. It threw an error: `404 | NOT FOUND`

Comment: Are you sure there is a post with the same `id` in database?

Comment: Yes, 

`>>> Post::find(23)
[!] Aliasing 'Post' to 'App\Models\Post' for this Tinker session.
=> App\Models\Post {#4412
     id: 23,
     user_id: 1,
     category_id: 1,
     title: "mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm",
     imagePath: "postImages/m8pjvkyVK1bvKLSmSmyV7MiCgQNVBysOQOw2gref.jpg",
     body: "nb",
     slug: "mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm",
     created_at: "2021-09-22 15:35:49",
     updated_at: "2021-09-22 15:35:49",
   }
>>> `

Comment: Maybe the problem comes from the route list, anyway, let me explain step by step, let's say the route looks like that `Route::delete('/posts/{post}/delete', [App\Http\Controllers\PostController::class, 'destroy']);`, the attacker registered as a user and he/she knows there no polices `if condition`, he will search in URLs or forms to get an id (primary key), easy, the attacker will make delete request by edit HTML url form or using postman; I hope this was clear, let's move to the controller@destroy by logic the function looking for the post if find it delete it if not return 404 that's all.

Comment: I get you clearly, I'm still trying to figure out why mine ain't deleting to see it in action. This is what I have when I run route:list `| DELETE    | posts/{post}` and I'm also using `my RouteKeyName as 'slug'` if that matters.